# How do I extract a date (dd-mm-yy) from a timestamp with timezone (timestamptz) in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp-with-timezone

My date column "timestamp" is currently listed as:

2020-11-16 20:27:38.033 +0000

It's formatted as timestamptz and I've tried every search on here and google to find a method to only pull the date part (in this example 2020-11-16) from the column so I can effectively start grouping data by Date.

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated.

Comment: What data type is the column `timestamp` (which btw. is a horrible name for a column)

Comment: The data type is "timestamptz"

Comment: Then Barbaros' answer is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (as you haven't stated) that the column is a string.  This shows how to convert:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT ('2020-11-16 20:27:38.033 +0000'::timestamp)::date;
    date    
------------
 2020-11-16
```

If it were already a timestamp, then just the `::date` cast would work.

Comment: This works, thank you! I'm relatively new, but how would I then covert every other type of date in the column? This only coverts that exact date listed as an example. Many thanks.

Comment: If your column is called timestamp (and see @a_horse_with_no_name comment on that), then `select "timestamp"::timestamp::date` would do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`::DATE`** casting or use **`TO_CHAR()`** conversion if the aim is just to display in that format
such as

```sql
SELECT your_ts_column::DATE AS val_as_date,
       TO_CHAR(your_ts_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS val_as_str 
  FROM your_table
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ebcb3da43e5bd9bc854bbc9f12b7b9d1)</kbd>

Comment: Final question, sorry. If I wanted to select the count of a column called "event" and then group by the date your script extracts, how would I go about this? I've tried:

SELECT timestamp::DATE AS val_as_date,
       TO_CHAR(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS val_as_str, count(event) 
  FROM mytable
  group by val_as_date

Comment: OK, surely you can use `SELECT timestamp::DATE AS val_as_date, COUNT(event)
  FROM t
 GROUP BY val_as_date` @Shuckyduckquackquack